# Configuration for generic comunication to ISP's Mailkit

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, mailkit

I'Have several configuration such as GMAIL, Hotmail, Office 365 etc and i want to all configuration works.

I have several that i have doubts. Example:

Configuration for sapo.pt SMTP

Server: smtp.sapo.pt

Port: 25

Port with SSL (only a smtp.sapo.pt): 465 ou 587

Requires authentication: YES

With my previous code the return messagem is:

Message: Connection temporarily refused, if it persists contact your ISP If your IP is a dynamic one (ADSL or dial-up, for instance) please reconfigure your outgoing settings to use your ISP server -- Ligacao temporariamente recusada, se o problema persistir contacte o seu fornecedor de servico Se acede a partir de um IP dinamico (ADSL ou dial-up, p.e.) por favor configure o envio para utilizar o seu ISP (#4.7.0)

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I've configured for sapo.pt smtp server and message that returns is: "Connection temporarily refused, if it persists contact your ISP If your IP is a dynamic one (ADSL or dial-up, for instance) please reconfigure your outgoing settings to use your ISP server -- Ligacao temporariamente recusada, se o problema persistir contacte o seu fornecedor de servico Se acede a partir de um IP dinamico (ADSL ou dial-up, p.e.) por favor configure o envio para utilizar o seu ISP (#4.7.0)".

Why that happen?

If is a private smtp the return message is:

"The SMTP server has unexpectedly disconnected."

Comment: Are you asking why you get different exception message strings? You'll probably have to dig into the .NET BCL source code to figure that out.

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I'm having problems with this same library using sapo email. I get "Auth failure" even though i'm using the password i use when accessing their website.